# angular4 AOT is broken when I use d3.js

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular2-aot

I am having an app using d3.js, when I compile the code using rollup, I got this error in browser,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
```

It is something like this from d3.js:

```
!function() {
  var d3 = {
    version: "3.5.17"
  };
  var d3_arraySlice = [].slice, d3_array = function(list) {
    return d3_arraySlice.call(list);
  };
  var d3_document = this.document;
```

I googled and seemed it is something related to: "useStrict"

But how can I disable it in tsconfig or rollup procedure?

Thanks

Comment: I think the `this` does not refer to the same thing when using AoT. Normally it refers to the `window` I think, with AoT it refers to the instance of the function. I think this is one of the reasons why direct-dom access is discouraged in angular2

Comment: I have to manually remove 'use strict' from build.js, then it can pass.